# Retrieve a cookie from a different path

Tags: javascript, path, dns, cookies

My current document URL is http: //127.0.0.1/foo and I need to change the value of a cookie for http: //127.0.0.1/bar.
document.cookie is empty because document's URL is foo.
For the moment, I just want to read the cookie value.
Any clue?

Answer (score 24):

When you create the cookie, if you set the path to '/' instead of 'foo' you will be able to read it anywhere on the domain, including '/foo', '/bar', etc.

Comment: I cannot change the cookie's creation and path. So it means it's impossible to access cookie of bar from foo?

Comment: It's not a big security issue because the cookie isn't really protected anyway. Due to SOP ignoring paths, cookie paths are not a meaningful security barrier.

Answer (score 16):

You can create an `<iframe>` pointed at a resource inside `/bar`, and cross-frame-script into it. eg:

```
<iframe src="/bar/blank.html" id="barframe"></iframe>

var barframe= document.getElementById('barframe');
var bardocument= 'contentDocument' in barframe? barframe.contentDocument : barframe.contentWindow.document; // IE compat
alert(bardocument.cookie);
```

Cookie `path=` is a convenience measure to prevent accidental cookie name clashes. Given that different paths share a JavaScript origin, it is not an effective security mechanism.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that cookie paths aren't a meaningful security wall.

Comment: The path is a performance feature, not a security one... 
I was missing the "barframe.contentDocument" part. Thanks a lot. +1 from me.

Answer (score 4):

You can't access cookies from a different path - otherwise it would be a security hole.

The only way I can think of is making `/bar` set a cookie whose `path=/` so that all pages in `/` (including `/foo`) could access it.

Answer (score 4):

As JJ and grawity have mentioned there is no way you can do this from your page. However, you have a work around.

i. Place an iframe which points to http://localhost/bar. Have a hidden element on the "bar" page where you store the cookie value. (let this iframe be 1*1 size so it is not visible).

ii. Use JavaScript on "foo" page to fetch the cookie value.

A similar approach (with modifications) can be used to write the cookie value too!

Thanks,

Ramjee.

Comment: Wouldn't this let anyone on the internet grab the cookie?