# How to read cookies of a deferent path

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies

I'm new to using cookies in Web development.

I can **write** cookies in JavaScript or Ruby on Rails, specifying a certain path like this:

In JavaScript

`document.cookie = 'some_key=123;path=/foo/bars'`

In Rails

`cookies[:some_key] = { value: 123, path: '/foo/bars' }`

On the other hand I cannot find how to **read** cookies in a certain path, either in JavaScript or Rails.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: I hope this will help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945862/retrieve-a-cookie-from-a-different-path

Answer (score 1):

You can't see cookies for other sites due to security  reason. you can access only the cookies set by your site. All the cookies you can see are in the document.cookie property.

Comment: Thanks. So can't I see cookies of another path, even if it is in the same domain?

Comment: @Taichi yes you can see all the cookie set under your domain.